# Show text search results in Resharper's "Find Results window"

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

When I search for text in my Visual Studio 2015 project or solution (using Ctrl-F) I can list all results by clicking "Find all" in the dropdown next to the text input. However, it only gives my a plain list of occurrences. I am wondering if there is a way to show the results in the Resharper "Find Results window" that is shown for instance when finding the usages of a symbol.

Particularly it would be great to be able to group by project and file and have a tree view in which some branches can be collapsed. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you use `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`F` (Find in Files) instead?

Comment: It gives me the same default Visual Studio result view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the [GoToWord **plugin**](https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/ReSharper.GoToWord/) for R#, available through the R# Extension Manager. Once installed you can do a **triple** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to get a full-text search using R#'s index, and then <kbd>Numpad +</kbd> will (as with all other R# searches) dump the results to the R# Find Results window. More info [on its github page](https://github.com/controlflow/resharper-gotoword).

I find it pretty much invaluable.

**BUT** (and this may be a deal-breaking BUT for you) - it [doesn't work past R# 8](https://github.com/controlflow/resharper-gotoword/issues/11). Sorry, should have checked.

Comment: That's a pity. I'm using Resharper Ultimate 16.1. The plugin sounds great but I cannot use it :-(